# Given one solution of ODE, how to find second solution?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The ODE of my question is
$$
(x^2 + 1)y'' - 2y = 2.
$$
Solution of homogeneous part of this equation is $1+x^2$.

How to find the general solution of this ODE?

I did this like, let other linearly independent solution $y_2$ is some function of $x$ multiplied by given solution
$$
y_2 = v(x)(1+x^2), \\
y_2'=(1+x^2)v'+2vx, \\
y_2''= (1+x^2)v''+4xv'+2v.
$$
Substituting  $y_2,y_2',y_2'' $ in ODE, we get
$$
(x^4+2x^2+1)v'' + 4x(x^2+1)v'=2.
$$
If this were homogeneous, I could have solved it. But how to proceed for this non-homogeneous ODE? Any help, much appreciated.

Comment: The general step is to find a _particular solution_ to the inhomogenous ODE $y_p$ and superpose it with the _general solution_ to the homogenous ODE. This works because you have a linear ODE here. TL;DR: Find $y_p$ and note that $(1+x^2)$ is not the only homogenous solution (I expect a solution space of dimension $2$).

Comment: A particular solution $y=-1$. General solution is obtained from homogenous ODE.You have 1, find the 2n one.  Just omit 2 in the right hand side of your last equaiton.

Comment: @AlexanderVigodner If I omit 2 from right, it will just give me a solution for homogeneous equation. But what about solution of particular part?

Comment: @AlexR, I know general solution is sum of homogeneous and particular part. I am stuck at the last equation, how to solve that since it is non-homogeneous.

Comment: @user3705273, I told you the particular solution is $y=−1$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A particular solution is $y=-1$.

You already found one homogeneous solution, $f_1=1+x^2$. What you suggested works well: guess $f_2=f_1 g(x)$, to get
$$\begin{align}
0&=(1+x^2)f_2''-2f_2\\&=(1+x^2)\left[f_1'' g +2 f_1'g'+f_1g''\right]-2 f_1 g(x)\\
&=(1+x^2)\left[2g +4xg'+(1+x^2)g''\right]-2 (1+x^2) g(x)\\
&=(1+x^2)\left[4xg'+(1+x^2)g''\right]
\end{align}$$
So you're left with the ODE $4xg'+(1+x^2)g''=0$, which can be written as
$$\frac{g''}{g'}=-\frac{4x}{x^2+1}$$
Integrating yields
$$\log(g')=-2 \log \left(x^2+1\right)+A$$
Here and onward I loosely use $A, B$ as integration constants, but their value changes from line to line...
$$g'=\frac{A}{(1+x^2)^2}$$
Integrating again gives
$$g=A \left(\frac{x}{x^2+1}+\arctan(x)\right)+B$$
So that 
$$f_2=(1+x^2)g=A x+A(1+x^2)\arctan(x)$$
I omitted the last term because it is proportional to $f_1$.

To conclude, the general solution is of the form 
$$y=-1+A\left[x+(1+x^2)\arctan(x)\right]+B(1+x^2)$$

Comment: thanks for your reply. I have a question here. In the original equation, there is a constant forcing term $2$ . $(1+x^2)$ is a solution of homogeneous part. However, in your solution, you seemed to have solved for homogeneous part again. So what about constant forcing term on right hand side?

Comment: The forcing is solved by the -1 term. This is the general technique: you find one particular solution $y_p$ (in our case, the constant function $y_p=-1$), and $n$ homogeneous solutions $y_1\dots y_n$ ($n$ is the degree of the ODE), and the most general solution is given by $$y=y_p+\sum A_i y_i$$