# Having trouble in solving second-order linear ordinary differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$(2x^2+1)y''-4xy'+4y=0$

$y_1(x) = x$ is given and I have to find $y_2(x)$ and solve equation. thanks.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/964360/given-one-solution-of-ode-how-to-find-second-solution does this will help?

Comment: if $y=f(x)$ is a solution of the equation $p(x)y''+q(x)y'+r(x)y=0$ then $y=c_1f(x)+c_2vf(x)$ is general solution where $$v=\frac{exp[-\int\frac{q(x)}{p(x)}]}{f(x)^2}$$

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Solve the second order ODE $(2x^2 + 1)y'' − 4xy' + 4y = 0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1856186/ode-2nd-order-non-constant-coefficient)

Comment: Oh it helps. But I'm having trouble after reducing order of equation